# Different package.json dependencies in React Native flavors

Tags: react-native

I have two flavors of the same Android application built in React Native (Lite and Pro).
I am able to inject specific variables in the app and gradle flavors, so I can have the two apps behaving differently at runtime.

However, the two flavors end up including the same modules from the same `package.json` even if one of the two flavors doesn't have all the functionalities and therefore doesn't need all the modules and the permissions set by manifest merger.

Is there a way to include/exclude the modules during the build phase without having to duplicate everything?

To give an example: the Lite version doesn't need the camera, but because I'm including `react-native-camera` into my `package.json`, the Lite version ends up requiring the camera permission even if it doesn't use it.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solutions?

Comment: Unfortunately no.